# installing multiple versions of curl on raspbian stretch

Tags: curl

The current version of raspbian stretch supports curl 7.52.1, however for an application I'm running I need curl 7.56 or above. How could I manually install the latest version of curl without breaking the linux distro by overwriting the version of curl it relies on?

For background, I know how to manually install curl:

```
wget https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.64.1.tar.gz
tar -xvf curl-7.64.1.tar.gz
cd curl-7*
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

But this will overwrite the version of curl without overwriting libcurl, causing issues, for instance executing `curl` via the terminal will result in the error:

```
Symbol lookup error undefined symbol: curl_mime_init
```

Which is because `curl_mime_init` is defined in the latest version of curl but not in libcurl 7.52.

I will update the symlink in /usr/bin to point to the new installed version of curl:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/curl /usr/bin/curl752
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/bin/curl /usr/bin/curl
```

When I run `curl --version` after this I get the following output, still with the mime error:

```
curl 7.64.1 (armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf) libcurl/7.52.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2l zlib/1.2.8 libidn2/0.16 libpsl/0.17.0 (+libidn2/0.16) libssh2/1.7.0 nghttp2/1.18.1 librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: 2019-03-27
```

So curl is upgraded, but libcurl is still 7.52.1.... which is likely causing the failures.

Comment: Does ./configure default to --prefix=/usr/local? If it does have you considered renaming /usr/bin/curl to /usr/bin/curl752 and replacing it with a symbolic link ln -s /usr/local/bin/curl /usr/bin/curl to make your new version the default version.

Comment: it does set the prefix. I hadn't but I just did this and the result was the same error, although now it is easy to turn back the error so I don't completely brick my raspberry pi. I'll update the main post with what error I see.

Comment: Looks like you're going to need to grab the latest tarball for libcurl and build that into /usr/local/lib.

Comment: So what I don't understand is that if I get the tarball of curl, it should install libcurl, yes? Otherwise, could you point me in the direction of clear instructions to install a specific version of libcurl that isn't apt-get

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/329535

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple steps to pointing to a new version, one is installing the newer version of the curl. Here are the steps to install a newer version of CURL and to point to the newer version of the libcurl library.

1. Download curl from source and unpack.

```
wget https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.64.1.tar.gz
tar -xvf curl-7.64.1.tar.gz
cd curl-7.64.1
```

2. Make curl, specifying a custom prefix during configuration.

```
export CURL_ROOT=~/curl_install
./configure --prefix=$CURL_ROOT
make -j
make install
```

3. Finally, point to the new curl lib.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$CURL_ROOT/lib/
```

Now, when you run the version of curl you have installed, you have to specifically point to it:

```
~/curl_install/bin/curl
```

If you just call `curl`, it will run the `curl` installed in the system.

**NOTE**: When doing this, you will now have a local copy of CURL in the `curl_install` directory, which is great so you aren't messing up the local version of curl (in case there are dependencies), however exporting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable will also change the library that the local version of CURL points to. If you need to have the other version of CURL used again, just point the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` back to the old curl lib:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="usr/local/lib"
```